# How to have LevelLoader method 'ignore' undefined entities?

Tags: java, android, xml, andengine

I am using a method of loading an xml file into a game as a level very similar to this:

```
private void loadLevel(int levelID)
{
final SimpleLevelLoader levelLoader = new SimpleLevelLoader(vbom);

final FixtureDef FIXTURE_DEF = PhysicsFactory.createFixtureDef(0, 0.01f, 0.5f);

levelLoader.registerEntityLoader(new EntityLoader<SimpleLevelEntityLoaderData>(LevelConstants.TAG_LEVEL)
{
    public IEntity onLoadEntity(final String pEntityName, final IEntity pParent, final Attributes pAttributes, final SimpleLevelEntityLoaderData pSimpleLevelEntityLoaderData) throws IOException 
    {
        final int width = SAXUtils.getIntAttributeOrThrow(pAttributes, LevelConstants.TAG_LEVEL_ATTRIBUTE_WIDTH);
        final int height = SAXUtils.getIntAttributeOrThrow(pAttributes, LevelConstants.TAG_LEVEL_ATTRIBUTE_HEIGHT);

        // TODO later we will specify camera BOUNDS and create invisible walls
        // on the beginning and on the end of the level.

        return GameScene.this;
    }
});

levelLoader.registerEntityLoader(new EntityLoader<SimpleLevelEntityLoaderData>(TAG_ENTITY)
{
    public IEntity onLoadEntity(final String pEntityName, final IEntity pParent, final Attributes pAttributes, final SimpleLevelEntityLoaderData pSimpleLevelEntityLoaderData) throws IOException
    {
        final int x = SAXUtils.getIntAttributeOrThrow(pAttributes, TAG_ENTITY_ATTRIBUTE_X);
        final int y = SAXUtils.getIntAttributeOrThrow(pAttributes, TAG_ENTITY_ATTRIBUTE_Y);
        final String type = SAXUtils.getAttributeOrThrow(pAttributes, TAG_ENTITY_ATTRIBUTE_TYPE);

        final Sprite levelObject;

        if (type.equals(TAG_ENTITY_ATTRIBUTE_TYPE_VALUE_PLATFORM1))
        {
            levelObject = new Sprite(x, y, resourcesManager.platform1_region, vbom);
            PhysicsFactory.createBoxBody(physicsWorld, levelObject, BodyType.StaticBody, FIXTURE_DEF).setUserData("platform1");
        } 
        else if (type.equals(TAG_ENTITY_ATTRIBUTE_TYPE_VALUE_PLATFORM2))
        {
            levelObject = new Sprite(x, y, resourcesManager.platform2_region, vbom);
            final Body body = PhysicsFactory.createBoxBody(physicsWorld, levelObject, BodyType.StaticBody, FIXTURE_DEF);
            body.setUserData("platform2");
            physicsWorld.registerPhysicsConnector(new PhysicsConnector(levelObject, body, true, false));
        }
        else if (type.equals(TAG_ENTITY_ATTRIBUTE_TYPE_VALUE_PLATFORM3))
        {
            levelObject = new Sprite(x, y, resourcesManager.platform3_region, vbom);
            final Body body = PhysicsFactory.createBoxBody(physicsWorld, levelObject, BodyType.StaticBody, FIXTURE_DEF);
            body.setUserData("platform3");
            physicsWorld.registerPhysicsConnector(new PhysicsConnector(levelObject, body, true, false));
        }
        else if (type.equals(TAG_ENTITY_ATTRIBUTE_TYPE_VALUE_COIN))
        {
            levelObject = new Sprite(x, y, resourcesManager.coin_region, vbom)
            {
                @Override
                protected void onManagedUpdate(float pSecondsElapsed) 
                {
                    super.onManagedUpdate(pSecondsElapsed);

                    /** 
                     * TODO
                     * we will later check if player collide with this (coin)
                     * and if it does, we will increase score and hide coin
                     * it will be completed in next articles (after creating player code)
                     */
                }
            };
            levelObject.registerEntityModifier(new LoopEntityModifier(new ScaleModifier(1, 1, 1.3f)));
        }            
        else
        {
            throw new IllegalArgumentException();
        }

        levelObject.setCullingEnabled(true);

        return levelObject;
    }
});

levelLoader.loadLevelFromAsset(activity.getAssets(), "level/" + levelID + ".lvl");
```

}

If I add an entity with some random type string in my level XML file that is not defined in that method and I run it, I get this stacktrace:

```
05-02 16:56:40.880: E/AndroidRuntime(3665): FATAL EXCEPTION: UpdateThread
05-02 16:56:40.880: E/AndroidRuntime(3665): org.andengine.util.level.exception.LevelLoaderException: java.lang.IllegalArgumentException
05-02 16:56:40.880: E/AndroidRuntime(3665):     at org.andengine.util.level.LevelLoader.loadLevelFromStream(LevelLoader.java:127)
05-02 16:56:40.880: E/AndroidRuntime(3665):     at org.andengine.util.level.LevelLoader.loadLevelFromAsset(LevelLoader.java:97)
05-02 16:56:40.880: E/AndroidRuntime(3665):     at org.andengine.util.level.LevelLoader.loadLevelFromAsset(LevelLoader.java:88)
05-02 16:56:40.880: E/AndroidRuntime(3665):     at org.andengine.util.level.LevelLoader.loadLevelFromAsset(LevelLoader.java:82)
05-02 16:56:40.880: E/AndroidRuntime(3665):     at com.package.game.GameScene.loadLevel(GameScene.java:478)
05-02 16:56:40.880: E/AndroidRuntime(3665):     at com.package.game.GameScene.setLevel(GameScene.java:1693)
05-02 16:56:40.880: E/AndroidRuntime(3665):     at com.package.game.SceneManager$1.onTimePassed(SceneManager.java:117)
05-02 16:56:40.880: E/AndroidRuntime(3665):
```

I need to be able to load different entities at different time from one level file, so how can I modify this method somehow so that it just kind of "ignores" entities that are not defined?

Comment: `catch` the `IllegalArgumentException` where it is thrown. This is in line 127 of `LevelLoader.java`

Comment: Where would the `try` part of that catch go?

Comment: right before the line line that throws the exception. Based on the stacktrace that would be line 127 of `LevelLoader.java`

Answer (score 1):

I have just looked in LevelParser.java method startElement(), you can bypass where the IllegalArgumentException exception is thrown in Andengine by creating a default Entity Loader. I.e.,

```
levelLoader.setDefaultEntityLoader( new IEntityLoader()
{

    @Override
    public void onLoadEntity(String pEntityName, Attributes pAttributes) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        Log.w("setDefaultEntityLoader","Unknown Entity");
    }

});
```

This default onLoadEntity() will then get called instead of the exception being raised. I tested it on GLES 1 and it works as expected.

Hope this helps.

Comment: Where should that go in the level loader method?

Comment: The order is not critical as long as it is before the levelLoader.loadLevelFromAsset() call. The relevent onLoadEntity interface instances get called for each corresponding entity name in the XML, the order in which they were registered before the method which actually parses the XML, (loadLevelFromAsset), is inconsequential. I would probably put it before you call levelLoader.loadLevelFromAsset() as the last registered loader purely so I could find it easier in the code if you have a lot of loaders registered.