# levelLoader.registerEntityLoader() is giving error

Tags: android, andengine

If anyone downvote this question kindly tell the reason for downvote

I am studying AndEngine and making demo project. I am making load level method

```
final SimpleLevelLoader levelLoader = new SimpleLevelLoader(vbom);
        levelLoader.registerEntityLoader(new EntityLoader<IEntityLoaderData>() {

            @Override
            public IEntity onLoadEntity(String pEntityName,
                    Attributes pAttributes) {
                // TODO Auto-generated method stub
                return null;
            }
        });
```

but its giving error on registerEntityLoader i.e shown in the photo below but it is used by so many people( [1st link](https://stackoverflow.com/q/16376949/3409600) and [2ndlink](http://www.matim-dev.com/full-game-tutorial---part-11.html) )

[image]) ). So kindly look over this question and it will be so thankful if you tell that where I am making mistake, Your answer is very valuable for me

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17803155/simplelevelloader-class-not-found-in-andengine-gles2 see this

Comment: @Golu this link is for SimpleLevelLoader class. Earlier I was getting that problem I solved that using GLES2- AnchorCenter but this time problem is in line levelLoader.registerEntityLoader